# How To Make A Button Refresh The Textarea Not The Page

Tags: php, button, textarea

```
<form action='Try.php' >
<textarea name='textarea'> Hello </textarea>
<input type='submit' value="Refresh The Text Area" >
</form>
```

This is my code

Comment: refresh textarea = clear textarea?

Comment: No I Mean I Want To Refresh It I Will Another thing With It

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, please try and define 'refresh the textarea'.

Comment: I Will Tell What I Want - I Have Another Script That Generating Random Passwords I Want A Button That Refresh The Text Area Did You Get It ?

Comment: Oh Man File This One Under - Waste Of Time Answering! :'(

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the preset text you are worrying about clearing, you can just use:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

If you want to clear the preset text as well, you have to turn to javascript. The following code uses a standard (not a reset) button to find the ID's text area and set its value to blank.

```js
function clearText()  {
 document.getElementById('TA1').value = "";
}
```

```html
<form action='Try.php' >
 <textarea id="TA1" name='textarea'> Hello </textarea>
 <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="clearText()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You , But I Want To Refresh It Not To Reset It :)

Comment: OK...what exactly do you mean by refresh?

Comment: I Will Tell What I Want - I Have Another Script That Generating Random Passwords I Want A Button That Refresh The Text Area Did You Get It ?

Comment: No, I don't get it

Comment: I Want To Make A Button To Refresh A Part Of Page Not All The Page When I Press On The Button It Give's Me a New Password , No Need To Refresh Full Page Just Need A Button To Refresh This Part , Did You Get It ??

Comment: You want Blank textarea?

Comment: Gyandeep Sharma , No I Just Want To Refresh The Text Area That's everything i want :/

Answer (score 0):

As i know, the only way to refresh part of website is use **ajax**, you can check the **jquery** api document, wish it can help you.  [jQuery API Document](https://api.jquery.com/)